# Does MemberwiseClone() works on Properties attribute?

Tags: c#

I have  a class  that can validate its Property  by  attribute ,like this :

```
public Class Person
{
[Required(ErrorMessage="Name is Required")]
 Public String Name{get;set;}
}
```

In my Application I have a orginal Object and a Copy from my Object :

```
void Maine()
{
  Person OrginalPerson=new Person();
  Person CopyPerson= (Person)OrginalPerson.MemberwiseClone();

}
```

when i use from OrginalPerson i can validate it ,but when i using  from CopyPerson my validation not worked!!!
i think that MemberwiseClone() cant  work on Properties attribute...I need that i can validate my CopyPerson to...

Comment: The property attribute is a property of a **class** not an **instance**, so i don't think that's the problem. Can we see the test code?

Answer (score 3):

MemberwiseClone copies all fields. If you create an automatic property there will be a backing field created for this, and MemberwiseClone will copy the property value.

This has no influence on any attributes that may or may not reside on properties on that class. Your CopyPerson will still be validated if you call validation code on your CopyPerson.